# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\tan(n\pi/(2n+1))^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

**My input**

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\tan\bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{\frac{2n+1}{n\pi}}\Bigg)^\frac{1}{n}\cdot\underbrace{\dfrac{\tan\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{\frac{2n+1}{n\pi}}\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{\frac{2n+1}{n\pi}}\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}}}_{\text{=1}}$

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

I will proceed further If I know that I am on correct path. Someone help me here.

Comment: I would recommend to use l'Hospitals rule. This limit is of the type $0^0$. I will define $f(n)=\tan (\frac{n\pi}{2n+1})^{1/n}$. If you use $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{e}^{\ln(f(n))}$, you will get a limit of the type $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ in the exponent. Since the exponential function is a continuous function, it is possible to put the $\lim$ into the exponential function. I hope this helps.

Comment: you mean limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi and $f(n)$, of course. Sorry for irritation.

Comment: Is the ${}^{\frac1n}$ inside or outside the $\tan$?

Comment: To the OP: can you clarify (cf. Mike Earnest's comment), please?

Comment: Please see my solution where I have argued both cases.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I am really sorry I had to go offline. It's not over the whole tan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)=\frac{\pi}2-\dfrac{\pi}{4n+2}\implies \tan \bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)=\frac1{\tan \bigg(\dfrac{\pi}{4n+2}\bigg)}\sim \dfrac{4n}{\pi}$$

and therefore

$$\left[\tan \bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}\sim \left(\dfrac{4n}{\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exponent is **outside** the $\tan$.

Comment: ahhhh ok...that's more interesting! Thanks I fix that.

Comment: @ClementC. Now it should be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

> **In case you meant**
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tan \Bigg( \Big(\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\Bigg) 
> \end{equation}
>   Let $L = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}$
>   \begin{equation}
>  \log L =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \frac{n\pi}{2n+1} 
> \end{equation}
>   As $n$ goes to infinity, $\frac{n\pi}{2n+1} $ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so
>   \begin{equation}
>  \log L =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log \frac{\pi}{2}}{n} = 0  
> \end{equation}
>   So 
>   \begin{equation}
>  L = e^{0} = 1
> \end{equation}
>   So the limits above 
>   $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\tan\bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \tan 1$$
>
> **In case you meant** 
>   \begin{equation}
>  \Big( \tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1} \Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}
> \end{equation}
>   Let 
>   \begin{equation}
>  L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log \Big( \tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1} \Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}
>   =
>   \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
>   \frac{1}{n}
>   \log \tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}
>   =
>   \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
>   \frac{\log \tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}}{n}
>   =
>   \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
>   \frac{\infty}{\infty}
> \end{equation}
>   Applying L'Hopital to the above, we get
>   \begin{equation}
>  L
>  =
>  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
>  \frac{ \big( \log \tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}\big)^{'}}{n^{'}}
>  =
>  \frac{\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}[1 + \cos^2(\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1})]}{\tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}}
>  =
>  \frac{[1 + \cos^2(\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1})]}{(2n+1)^2\tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}}
> \end{equation}
>   The numerator is bounded and denominator goes to infinity, so
>   \begin{equation}
>  L = 0
> \end{equation}
>   and 
>   \begin{equation}
>  \Big( \tan \frac{n\pi}{2n + 1} \Big)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
>  \rightarrow e^0 = 1 
> \end{equation}

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exponent is **outside** the $\tan$.

Comment: yep me too @ClementC.

Comment: So you posted an answer to a statement you suspected was not the right one?

Comment: So $L = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^0 = 1$. What is your problem with that ?

Comment: In general, $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\tan(x_n)^{1/n} \neq \lim_{n\to\infty }\tan(x_n^{1/n})$$ and you computed the second limit.

Comment: yeah i know but that's what he meant right ? He wants to compute the second one ..

Comment: I don't think so. "I'm pretty sure the exponent is **outside** the $\tan$"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82799/discussion-between-ahmad-bazzi-and-clement-c).

Comment: yeah but i'm pretty sure he meant $\tan (x_n)^{1/n} $ and not $(\tan x_n)^{1/n}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\tan=\frac{\sin}\cos$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\big(\frac\pi2(1-\frac1{n})\big)}{\cos\big(\frac\pi2(1-\frac1{n})\big)}\right)^{1/n}
$$
Now use the symmetry $\cos(\theta)=\sin(\frac\pi2-\theta)$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\cos\big(\frac\pi{2n}\big)}{\sin\big(\frac\pi{2n}\big)}\right)^{1/n}
$$
Finally, use the small order terms of the Taylor series for $\sin,\cos$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+O(1/n^2)}{\frac\pi{2n}+O(1/n^3)}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+O(1/n^2))^{1/n}
$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$, the same is true for $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+O(1/n^2))^{1/n}$.